# TestNG parallel execution behavior doesn't match the expected one

Tags: java, testng

I'm currently facing a problem that I can't identify.

I'm trying to run tests in parallel using testNG. I have no problem running different tests in parallel, but when I try to run a single test multiple time in different thread, I have a strange behavior.

So, I tried to debug to find out the problem. The error occurs when I'm trying to get a value from the TestNG XML configuration file :

```
public class LocalWebDriverListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LocalWebDriverListener.class);

    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        log.debug("BEGINNING: LocalWebDriverListener.beforeInvocation");
        if (method.isTestMethod()) {
            //Error on this line
            String browserName = method.getTestMethod().getXmlTest().getLocalParameters().get("browserName");
            //getXmlTest() returns null
            WebDriver driver = LocalDriverFactory.createInstance(browserName);
            DriverManager.setWebDriver(driver);
        } else {
            log.warn("Not a TestNG test");
        }
        log.debug("END: LocalWebDriverListener.beforeInvocation");
    }
}
```

I don't understand why getXmlTest() returns null only when threadPoolSize > 1 in @Test parameters.

```
public class TestClass {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestClass.class);

    @Test(invocationCount = 5, threadPoolSize = 5)
    public void testMethod1() {
        invokeBrowser("http://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Test executed using WebDriver" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="my.organization.WebDriverListener" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="Tests run in Chrome">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome" />
        <packages>
            <package name="my.organization.tests" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Can you help me on this one ?

Thanks

Comment: Uhm... Can't you use the builtin mechanism provided by TestNG's @Test annotation? Or is that what you already use?

Comment: I edited the question. I'm using the builtin mechanism, but I have to get a value from the TestNG XML config (that is working if I don't have a TheadPoolSize greater than 1)

Comment: Can't you use a `@BeforeClass` to set the parameter instead, and use it in your test method?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do that easily. I used the getXmlTest().getLocalParameters().get("browserName"); to avoid writing this by myself. If I can't use it, I will get these parameters in another way

Comment: Well, to be honest I never use XML for configuring my tests, so... :)

Comment: Could you please share your testng.xml?

Comment: @EnotEnotovich I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that IInvokedMethod does not know about testng.xml
Replace 
`String browserName = method.getTestMethod().getXmlTest().getLocalParameters().get("browserName");` 
with
`String browserName = testResult.getTestContext().getCurrentXmlTest().getLocalParameters().get("browserName");`

Comment: It actually worked pretty well. Why IInvokedMethod doesn't know about the XML in that case, and when I don't try to run the same method in parallel, it knows the XML ?

Comment: It seems like a bug or this functionality is used when you create xml suite programmatically and define XMLSuite value from code.

Comment: I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1029) for this case.

Comment: Also `method.getTestMethod().getTestClass().getXmlTest()` would work in parallel case

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. I'm going to test that